# ogre build fails with freetype.h error, OS X 10.8, Hydro

Tags: ros-hydro, osx, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While trying to install Hydro on OS X 10.8, with XCode 5.0.2, installing ogre through `brew install ogre` fails with an `freetype.h not found` error.

```
/tmp/ogre-ZCKQ/ogre_src_v1-7-4/OgreMain/src/OgreFont.cpp:44:10: fatal error: 'freetype.h' file not found
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
         ^
/usr/local/include/freetype/config/ftheader.h:173:24: note: expanded from macro 'FT_FREETYPE_H'
#define FT_FREETYPE_H  <freetype.h>
```

I have the following symbolic links in my machine for freetype.

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1/include/freetype2 /opt/x11/include/freetype2
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype
```

The complete error stream is gisted here : https://gist.github.com/karthikkovalam/11376100

I am not sure if I have all the symbolic links properly set. Kindly help me with this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158271/ogre-build-fails-with-freetype.h-error,-os-x-10.8,-hydro/) by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-04-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is related:

https://github.com/osrf/homebrew-simulation/issues/6

Basically if you use the symbolic link to get one of the Python package's to install, then ogre will not work.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on 2014-04-28**:
That perfectly worked. Thanks.

**Comment by [Arjav](https://answers.ros.org/users/18918/arjav/) on 2014-06-19**:
Hi! I am trying to install ROS Hydro on my MAC 10.8.5. Can you please outline the steps which you carried out to install ogre? I have been stuck here for a while and can't seem to find a way out.

Thanks.